# macro to paste pre-configured text

Tags: shortcut-keys, clipboard-manager

I am looking to avoid ever typing in my email address again. Is there a way to configure a key to paste some pre-set bit of text like my email.

I'd like this to work across all applications ideally.

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### 1) Install xclip and xdotool

```
sudo apt-get install xclip xdotool
```

#### 2) Make a file myscript.sh

```
mkdir ~/bin
gedit ~/bin/myscript.sh
```

#### 3) Copy paste this script into it

```
#!/bin/bash
TEXT="myname@address.com"
printf '%s' "$TEXT" | xclip -i -selection clipboard
xdotool key --clearmodifiers "ctrl+v"
```

#### 4) Make the file executable

```
chmod +x ~/bin/myscript.sh
```

#### 5) Make a shortcut

Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom shortcuts -> click [+]

- Name: anything, Command: /home/USERNAME/bin/myscript.sh

  - Replace the USERNAME with your username
- Click on the `Disabled` text and then press your magical keystroke. For example `Ctrl-Shift-S`
- You may have to restart unity with `setsid unity` or by logging in and out to make the shortcut work. (at least i had this bug on Ubuntu 13.10)

#### Troubleshooting

If you have any problems with pasting the text. Try changing `xdotool key` to `xdotool sleep 0.5 key`. It gives you time to take your hands off the keyboard before xdotool tries to press "Ctrl-V"

Comment: For me, my TEXT variable had spaces in it.  In order for that to work properly, I had to use `printf "$TEXT"` instead of `printf '%s' $TEXT`.  What is the advantage of using the `%s`?

Comment: If you don't want this script to purge you current clipboard, then at the beginning, put `OLD_TEXT=$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)` and at the end put `sleep 1; printf "$OLD_TEXT" | xclip -i -selection clipboard`.

Comment: I am not going to argue that this will work, but isn't there some kind of tool that makes this a little less hand-built?

Comment: @Shadoninja There's AutoKey, which tries to tackle this, but for me when it pasted it dropped letters randomly from the paste text.

Comment: That edit is definitely necessary for me. Any way to get it to do new lines? I've tried adding `\n` to my TEXT variable, but it doesn't seem to work. In Firefox it's all one line, but in gedit, it's OK.

Comment: Worth pointing out: one might try to circumvent the clipboard by setting the shortcut command to something like `xdotool type --clearmodifiers myname@myaddress` , but that ends up being flaky.

Answer (score 1):

The previous reply is from 2013 and we need something that works on 2021.

`xdotool` doesn't work on wayland.

`xdotool` does not always work as expected (i.e. it's sometimes very flaky).

An alternative tool to `xdotool` is `ydotool`.

#### 1. install ydotool and xclip

```
sudo apt install -y ydotool xclip
```

#### 2a. if you want to type text from the clipboard

Copy/paste is disabled on some applications and you may want to use this tool to type text instead of pasting.

Create a file `~/bin/myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

xclip -o | ydotool type --delay 1000 --key-delay 70 --file -
```

#### 2b. if you just want to type a text

This is easier.

Create a file `~/bin/myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

TEXT="ad eundem rivum lupus et agnus venerant"
ydotool type --delay 1000 --key-delay 70 $TEXT
```

#### 3. create a shortcut

Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom shortcuts -> click [+]

- Name: anything, Command: /home/USERNAME/bin/myscript.sh

  - Replace the USERNAME with your username
- Click on the `Disabled` text and then press your magical keystroke. For example `Ctrl-Shift-S`

Answer (score 1):

Try espanso which is a pretty good system-wide text expander:

```
https://espanso.org/
```

Comment: nice tool, but wayland is still in the works